# On which date was Christ born?

Tags: history, christmas, birth-of-jesus, historical-jesus

Most Christians celebrate the birth of Christ (Christmas) on December 25. But was this really the day of Christ's birth? **What was the actual date of Christ's birth?**

Comment: @FMS: Thanks for the edit attempt. However, given the relatively ancient nature of this question, and the existing answers, I'd rather leave this question as is, and closed, than to invalidate the existing answers.  Feel free to ask your overview question separately, if you're so inclined.

Comment: Understood. From experience asking that question following my edit and most likely it will be marked duplicate  and pointed to this one i.e., an answer is available here. So agree to leave things as they are. PS You asked a good question and I believe I benefited from from the ensuing research. Mahalo!

Comment: @FMS: Questions should rarely ever be made duplicates of closed questions, unless the new question has the same flaw as the closed question.

Comment: Cf. e.g. [Who is credited with being the first to use these terms “conservatives”, “traditionalists”, “progressives and liberals” within the Catholic Church? (duplicate)](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34151/who-is-credited-with-being-the-first-to-use-these-terms-conservatives-tradit). They are a few more.

Comment: Here is another: [According to Catholic theology, why are there two and only two processions in the Godhead? (duplicate)](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36868/according-to-catholic-theology-why-are-there-two-and-only-two-processions-in-th) which was marked a duplicate when mine was asking from a **Catholic** perspective.

Comment: In  your first example, the duplicate happened nearly a year before the target was closed.  In the second case, the target isn't even closed (although I agree with you that the Catholic perspective makes yours unique and better)

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know there is no proof of any certain date of Christ's birth. And it is only by tradition that we accept it as the 25th of December. Now I'm not one for following tradition for traditions sake, but according to [this site](http://www.bibleserralta.com/JesusbornDecember.html) a lot of the evidence that people provide to rule out December as Christ's birthday is not rooted in fact. I don't think the exact day is important to salvation myself, but the fact that He was born. According to the author of that site the movement to suggest he couldn't have been born in december was started by the Jehovah's Witnesses, I don't know if that's true but that's what he claims.

The author dosen't claim that Jesus definitely was born on Dec. 25th. But claims that we just can't rule that out. Here are a couple of his points:

- Those against the December date claim that it was too cold for
  shepherds to be out in the field in winter; However it didn't seem to
  actually get that cold in Bethlehem in December, and even if it did
  shepherds would in fact stay out in the fields even in colder
  weather.
- Claims are made that tradition puts it in December beacause of the
  pegan winter solstice, the problem with that argument is that the
  winter solstice is on the 21st to the 22nd, not the 25th, and there
  are thousands of pegan holidays so ANY day is some pegan celebration
  in some part of the world.

So can it be proved that it was the 25th of December? No. Can it be disproved? Probably not.

Does it matter more that it happened on a certain day or just the fact that it happened?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the argument against the December date is considerably older than the Witnesses.

Comment: I understand the 25th is a birthday for a number of pagan gods how is this handled?

Comment: @ChimangoChisuwo every day is a birthday for some pegan "god" , why would that matter at all? Having said that in the vast majority of cases that Christians are accused of boworing pagan traditions or dates, they are simply made up when you look at actual evidence, people come up with a story that sounds good about how close some pagan celebration or something was , but the dates are almost always wrong and the traditions cited rarely are what was claimed. Just a sad attempt to somehow discredit Christianity.

Answer (score 5):

[Jonathan Cahn](http://www.theharbinger-jonathancahn.com/About/) a **Messianic** Jewish Rabbi and **pastor** has a very interesting and intriguing take on this.

His detective work, drawing from Scripture and Jewish Laws, Traditions, and on Hebrew Holy Days, leads him to propose **Nisan 1, 3756** i.e. [**March 20, 6 BC**](http://www.cgsf.org/dbeattie/calendar/?roman=-5).

### 1st Clue: Shepherds at Night

- According to the Rabbis in the Talmud, shepherds kept watch by night from around March to the next rainy season [in Autumn].
- Birth at night in Autumn is eliminated because of the feast of Tabernacles during that season and all males had to be in Jerusalem.
- The shepherds at night also watch out for new lambs because of the lambing season being in spring: Mar/Apr [Nisan].
- Who better to greet the arrival of the Lamb of God than shepherds?
- Bethlehem was from whence the lambs for the Temple sacarfice came.

### 2nd Clue: Hebrew Holy Days

Central events of the Messiah and his time on earth happen on Hebrew Holy Days, therefore his birth must have been on a Hebrew Holy Day, and therefore the birth points to Nissan 1, beginning of the Hebrew Year.

### 3rd Clue: Moon Mystery

Jesus died on passover 14/15 Nissan on full moon, therefore he must have been born on new moon 1st Nissan.

### 4th Clue: Stars

The Magi's visit, the Massacre of the Infants, and knowng from History when Herod died (4 BC) points to the year of birth being around 6 BC.

### 5th Clue: Circumstances surrounding John the Baptist's conception

From the priestly calendar using the Talmud and Dead Sea Scrolls, the date of the duty of the division of Abi′jah to which priest Zechari′ah, John's Father belonged, can be determined.

### Final Clue: The OT Tabernacle

The date on which the OT Tabernacle was to be raised was Nisan 1. *(The Word was made flesh and dwelt [pitched his tent] among us.)*

See more here: Jonathan Cahn - [When was Messiah Jesus born?, Connie Oelbaum | YouTube](https://youtu.be/9dcy1VF3OOk).

---

*How does this compare to Catholic Tradition?*

From [this article](http://taylormarshall.com/2011/12/pope-benedict-xvi-december-25-as.html) by Dr Taylor Marshall, the Church reasoning is that Christ was conceived on March 25, a date that has cosmic significance - e.g. March 25 was thought to be the first day of creation - and therefore born 9 months later on December 25. **The Rabbi has him born, NOT conceived, in spring.** Pretty fascinating stuff.

Comment: @user13992: Very logical and well thought out answer. It would make sense that Jesus was born on a Jewish holiday which would explain why Jerusalem was crowded at the time of his birth. Sheep despite the fact that are covered in wool are particularly suited for winter cold thus  shepherds would not have them out all night.

Answer (score 3):

We Armenians *do* informally celebrate the birthday of Christ on December 25th, but to celebrate his birth on the 6th of January is religiously accurate.

The historical reasoning behind this is that until the fourth century, Christ's birth was celebrated on January 6th across all Christian faiths, but for most was moved to December 25th in order to cleanse Christianity of all pagan traces (leftover from former pagan practices). Armenia was not included because as a nation it didn't adopt the pagan practice to begin with (and Armenia was the first to accept Christianity as a nation).

Most Christian faiths now recognize December 25th as Christ's birthday and January 6th as the Feast of Epiphany. However, both used to be celebrated—and currently are, by most Armenian religions—on January 6th.

<sub>[Source](http://www.littlearmenia.com/html/little_armenia/armenian_christmas.asp)</sub>

Comment: Many alternative dates are cited; September seems a popular month; when something is (or was) celebrated is often of little relation to the *actual* event. My interpretation of the question suggests to me that the January date is of no more repute that Dec 25th...

Comment: I disagree that when something is celebrated is of little relation to the actual event...  When has someone ever wished you a "happy birthday" six months from the actual date?

Comment: My understanding of the January 6th date isn't because 1/6 is more "accurate" but rather because the Orthodox churches never accepted the Gregorian calendar reforms that shifted things around by 13 days.

Comment: @TheGeeko61: I often celebrate my birthday on a date other than my actual birthday. I've also met a couple of people who didn't know their actual birthday, but that didn't stop us from guessing, and having a party anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question which has plagued me for many decades.  I am truly shocked that a [similar question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4772/when-did-christmas-the-birth-of-christ-first-begin-as-a-christian-celebration) received such little response during this season.

In other discussions here, we all can agree that **no one** can answer the question directly.  No one **knows** the actual date of Christ's birth.

To know what one does not know is a sign of scholarship.  Sometimes, the wisest answer to a question is **"I don't know."**  To continue rambling in the answer is to address issues not identified in the question.  (As the previous sentence just demonstrated.)

`end of answer`

Comment: Don't you think Mary might have known?  And by extension the apostles who asked her, "So... when was Jesus born anyway?"

Comment: Good point... which is why I state in the present tense... that no one can answer... I didn't say that no one *has ever answered.*

Answer (score 1):

The January 6 date used in the Armenian calendar is simply based on the greek calendar which placed nisan 14 on the greek month of Artemisios 14th (April 6). The west placed 'Good Friday/Nisan 14" on March 25th. (an ancient belief that an influential person dies on the day he is conceived). Thus nine months after the feast day of the Anunciation on the liturgical calendar, will be placed Christmas.

As the liturgical calendar evolved in the Eastern half of the Roman empire, the roman/byzantine east split the dual feasts of the Nativity and Baptism of the Lord. Adopting the roman/western date Dec 25 for the nativity according to the flesh, and retaining Jan 6 as the Theophany of Christ in the Jordan. Armenians who tended to be outside the empire retained the original eastern 4th century feastday. It is the 12 days between Dec 25 and Jan 6 where we get the concept of the "12 days of Christmas".

The January 7th date for Christmas used by Eastern Orthodox christians and by the Coptic church is simply based on the julian calendar. January 7 on our business/ gregorian calendar is december 25th on the julian calendar. In a few more decades January 8 Gregorian reckoning will become the day that Orthodox christians (on the julian calendar) will celebrate Christmas- yet it will still be Dec 25th on that calendar.

Gregory Nazianzen bishop of Constantinople gave a series of homilies (orations 38-40) for these feast days which was one of the transition years where the celebration of Theophany/Christmas was split into two (there is some controversy on which day; dec 25 or jan 6 they were delivered on). Regardless they are treated by Gregory as a single feast day. They were given in 380/381AD right about the time of the adoption of Dec 25 for Christmas in Constantinople: Oration 38 (chapter 3) and orations 39-40 make clear this was still viewed as a single feast:

:http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/310238.htm

There is also a very interesting article published years ago in Biblical Archeology Review about this;

http://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/biblical-topics/new-testament/how-december-25-became-christmas/

Comment: This is quite informative. Could you perhaps add some references, too?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks also for offering an interesting answer. For some further tips on writing good answers here, please see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) I do hope you'll stick around!