Does the Bible tell us why God gave to his people the Ten Commandments?
Does the Bible tell why God gave the Ten Commandments to his people Israel, as depicted in book of Exodus?
Does the Bible tell us what was the reason why God gave the Ten Commandments?

Interesting question. I've found one reason in Leviticus 26. If they kept his laws he would send rain in its season and the land will yield its produce. There is also a strange statement in Leviticus 18 too. If you keep them, you shall live by them.

see this along with my answer. The code of law serves as the summary of the law and the law serves as the tree or book of life, not just earthly abundant life but eternal life.  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14759/was-eternal-life-promised-by-the-mosaic-law

The twentieth chapter of Exodus is neither a beginning nor an ending, in and of itself. The entire book of Genesis must not only be read but must be fully assimilated in order to give a foundation of understanding to which the book of Exodus may be added.
Eden must be understood and what occurred in it - that humanity does not, and cannot, live by the knowledge of good and evil, of which law, and specifically the law expressed in ten sayings, is the highest form.
But if humanity only ever dies as a result of attempting to partake (to eat) of such knowledge then why is it given at all ?
And if Paul's words are understood aright, that 'by the law is the knowledge of sin' then why does God especially come down upon Sinai, his presence causing the earth to quake and the rocks to split apart ?
What use is this knowledge if all it will do is highlight sin, exacerbate sin and multiply sin ? See the whole chapter of Romans 7.
The reason is that God desired to express, among a particularly chosen set of people (the natural seed of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob) the everlasting covenant, Genesis 17:7, Psalm 105:10, Hebrews 13:20, which could not yet be revealed until the coming of the Son of God, Jesus Christ.
But for God to draw near to sinful humanity, already fallen in regard to the knowledge of good and evil, already failed of its true purpose (the worship of God) already compromised in their head, Adam, then the law must be stated, and that in full, as part of the agreement made by Deity to the children of Israel in order for them to set forth a representation (ark, tabernacle, cherubim, mercy seat, sacrifices and priesthood) in the wilderness and, later, within Canaan.
Thus the law which humanity had fallen under in Eden is stated in full and in all its possible parts not only in ten sayings, which summarise all, but in four books - Exodus, Leviticus, Numbers and Deuteronomy, the whole being, the Law of Moses.
The gospel laid out in detail by Paul the apostle, and Peter and James and John and Jude and the writer to the Hebrews, fully explains how this law is dealt with in respect of God's chosen people, whom he redeemed by sending his own Son, Jesus Christ who was offered up to bear sins in his own body on the tree, and also, further, to yield up his life that sin, itself, might be eradicated in the death of a suitable sacrifice to satisfy the righteousness of God.
This is a massively important question, Why was law set before Israel ? and cannot be neglected by anyone who would draw near to God, through Christ, in order to experience justification unto life.

Quite well said. +1

This question is actually backward.
God didn't choose his people and then decide to give the Commandments to them.
His Commandments (rules for living a Godly life) already existed; he chose the people to demonstrate to the world what happens when a nation obeys or disobeys those Commandments.
The idea is best described in Deuteronomy 28, often called the Blessings and Curses Chapter:
Blessings:

1 And it shall come to pass, if thou shalt hearken diligently unto the voice of the LORD thy God, to observe and to do all his commandments which I command thee this day, that the LORD thy God will set thee on high above all nations of the earth:
2 And all these blessings shall come on thee, and overtake thee, if thou shalt hearken unto the voice of the LORD thy God.
3 Blessed shalt thou be in the city, and blessed shalt thou be in the field.
4 Blessed …
…
9 The LORD shall establish thee an holy people unto himself, as he hath sworn unto thee, if thou shalt keep the commandments of the LORD thy God, and walk in his ways.
10 And all people of the earth shall see that thou art called by the name of the LORD; and they shall be afraid of thee.
…
13 And the LORD shall make thee the head, and not the tail; and thou shalt be above only, and thou shalt not be beneath; if that thou hearken unto the commandments of the LORD thy God, which I command thee this day, to observe and to do them:
14 And thou shalt not go aside from any of the words which I command thee this day, to the right hand, or to the left, to go after other gods to serve them.

Curses:

27 But it shall come to pass, if thou wilt not hearken unto the voice of the LORD thy God, to observe to do all his commandments and his statutes which I command thee this day; that all these curses shall come upon thee, and overtake thee:
28 Cursed shalt thou be in the city, and cursed shalt thou be in the field.
29 Cursed shall be thy basket and thy store.
…
43 The stranger that is within thee shall get up above thee very high; and thou shalt come down very low.
44 He shall lend to thee, and thou shalt not lend to him: he shall be the head, and thou shalt be the tail.
45 Moreover all these curses shall come upon thee, and shall pursue thee, and overtake thee, till thou be destroyed; because thou hearkenedst not unto the voice of the LORD thy God, to keep his commandments and his statutes which he commanded thee:
46 And they shall be upon thee for a sign and for a wonder, and upon thy seed for ever.
…
63 And it shall come to pass, that as the LORD rejoiced over you to do you good, and to multiply you; so the LORD will rejoice over you to destroy you, and to bring you to nought; and ye shall be plucked from off the land whither thou goest to possess it.

Much of Hebrew scripture is the written history of Israel.
Unlike most nations, where history is written by the winners and so records only their victories and prosperous times, the Bible records the full history of the Israelites, warts and all.
It records that when there was a good king, who respected God's laws, the people followed him, and the nation prospered.
It also records that when the king didn't follow God's laws, the people followed, and the nation declined, sometimes even into complete captivity by other nations.
1 Corinthians 10:11 calls the Israelites an example:

Now all these things happened unto them for ensamples: and they are written for our admonition, upon whom the ends of the world are come.
(NLT) These things happened to them as examples for us. They were written down to warn us who live at the end of the age.

The Israelites weren't chosen to be God's favourites, they were chosen to be an example to the world, both of good and of bad.

Ray I want to update this answer...however, your ramble into pharasees "stop signs"  ... a great answer went pearshaped. If you can remove that, I will upvote the rest as is.

@adam, agreed. Thanks for pointing it out.

"chosen" means being favoured/favourited; thus the purpose of being example for others is not incompatible with being favourite.

@Michael16 says ""chosen" means being favoured/favourited". — As in the Roman practice of decimation, where every tenth person in a town would be chosen for execution to set an example of the Roman power?

of course, the connotation in the covenantal context of bible, chosen is being favoured, not to be killed.

The reason for such code tablet was to establish national law or constitution for the nation. The oldest known code of law is the Sumerian law. The Sumerian law code of Ur-Nammu —the oldest known code of laws (21st century BC). When Moses gave the people a set of laws, this was not a new idea to them, since other law codes have been found from centuries before Moses’ time. The summarised codes were written on the tablet for public display. Their purpose was the same as the constitution, and to establish justice/righteousness. The codes were given divine authority, which entailed divine blessings and curses tied to them. The purpose of the law is to serve as the book of life: "that you may live" (Deut 30:6).
Public Display of Legal Codes

Code of Hammurabi:
The Code of Hammurabi, created around 1754 BCE, was inscribed on a large basalt stele that stood approximately 2.25 meters tall. This stele was prominently displayed in public places, allowing citizens to see the laws that governed them.
The top of the stele features an image of King Hammurabi receiving the laws from Shamash, the sun god, which emphasized the divine authority behind these laws. The text includes around 4,130 lines detailing various laws and their corresponding punishments.
Code of Ur-Nammu:
The Code of Ur-Nammu, dating back to approximately 2100-2050 BCE, is considered one of the oldest known law codes. While it is less clear whether it was displayed similarly as Hammurabi's code, it was likely publicized during its time.
The laws were inscribed on clay tablets and disseminated among scribes and officials, making them accessible for legal reference. This practice helped ensure that the laws were known and followed by the populace.

Purpose of Public Display:

Displaying these codes served multiple purposes:
Legal Awareness: It informed citizens about their rights and responsibilities under the law.
Deterrence: By making laws visible, it acted as a deterrent against wrongdoing, as people were aware of the consequences for various offences.
Legitimacy: Public display reinforced the authority of the ruler and the legal system, demonstrating that justice was administered in accordance with established laws.

In summary, ancient law codes from the Near East, including those from Babylon and Israel, often included elements of divine blessing and cursing as a means of encouraging compliance with the laws. These provisions served to reinforce the idea that adherence to legal statutes was not only a civic duty but also a religious obligation tied to the favor or displeasure of the gods. This connection between law and divine authority reflects a broader cultural understanding of justice and morality in ancient societies.

On one level it certainly serves this function but, on another level, Paul refered to it as a ministry of condemnation and as a ministry of death.  A schoolmaster to lead/drive us to Christ.

That's twisting the context in which Paul writes that to call it condemnation. It maybe said with respect to the harshness and compulsion of the exhaustive regulations, thus, compared to new cov, it was difficult. The law did serve as the guardian until Christ, but its main purpose was to give life, like all laws were supposed to. The negative characterisation of law is written in context to convince superiority of New cov. Paul didn't condemn law. Death is still a consequence of the new covenant.

If a law could have been given which could have given life then righteousness would be by the law. Galatians 3:21. There's nothing wrong with the law. Paul declares as much.  The problem is it is weak through the flesh.  Jesus had to come in order to condemn sin in the flesh. In Galatians and other places Paul very clearly says that the law could not give life or righteousness and if such a law could have been given it would have been given and life would be by it.

Those statements are contradictory "Law could never give life", and "nothing wrong with the law". See my topic on Gal 3:21b "If a law had been given" translation on hermeneutics.SE. The weakness of the law arguments are only comparative in favour for something better, he's not making normative arguments.  It described how normal was it to make such argument (Will share later). Longenecker cited O'neil on this in his commentary. Also see my ans here https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48985/could-the-law-give-life/60681

The simple fact is that those Israelites of old who pursued obedience to the law by faith are the ones who received life and the ones who pursued obedience in order to establish their own righteousness (flesh) fell short.  It has always, always, always been faith in the operation of God that grants life.  Law was given but Law was unable to give life because of sin in the flesh.  Law doesn't remove sin, it points it out and condemns it.

The attitude of keeping the law is never in question in the NT. The Galatians epistle explains the temporal invalidity or abrogation of the law making it invalid, hence, it's not just useless for gentiles, but it cancels the grace (Gal 5). I explained in "sola fide/faith alone" topics that justification before men is non-issue. Law cannot give life after its purpose ended. It was temporal.

I think the best reason is found in Leviticus 18:3 God did not want the Israelites to "follow the practices of the Egyptians or Caananites"
"Lev18:3You must not follow the practices of the land of Egypt, where you used to live, and you must not follow the practices of the land of Canaan, into which I am bringing you. You must not walk in their customs"
God set aside the
Israelites as His special people...they were to be different from the "worldly" people in region.
Deuteronomy 7:6
For you are a holy people, who belong to the LORD your God. Of all the people on earth, the LORD your God has chosen you to be his own special treasure

While the scriptures aren't overly explicit on the matter of why God gave us the 10 commandments or the Mosaic Law, I will share with you my perspective based upon my own theological studies on the core themes of the scriptures.
In the beginning, on the 6th day, God created man and woman. All the other acts of creation led up to this: the pinnacle of creation. For man, unlike the rest of creation, was made in God's own image. Unlike other things that were created simply by God's commands, with man he is far more involved - molding his body, and breathing life into him. God further gives man power and authority over the rest of creation - to rule over it.
In short: man was created to be like God. In fact, this is what it means (spiritually) to be a Son of God (or anyone else): that we learn and live according to His ways.
For this same reason, we are commanded to be Holy - for God is Holy, and we are to be like Him.
So then, God instructs us through things like the 10 commandments, the Covenants, the Law and the Prophets so that we maybe Holy like him; so that we maybe sons and daughters of God.
Of course, there is also a purpose for those who refuse to obey and do what is right: to hold them accountable. For by teaching people what is right and good, they cannot do evil and then turn around and say "well, I didn't know!"
Thus the knowledge of good and evil, such as found in the 10 commandments, serves both to teach us to be Holy people of God and to condemn sin and remove any excuse of ignorance.

I've had to down vote this answer. We were never created to be LIKE God. Man was Created in the image of God. These are two very different notions. "Like God" suggests equality with/deity, that is very definately anti biblical. Satan tricked Eve into eating the fruit by saying..."you shall become like God" knowing good and evil! If you read Isaiah chapters 40-45, God very definately does not share/delegate his divinity or his authority with us...we were never "like God"!

@adam To be in his image is to be like Him. You are reading your own ideas into it as far as it meaning equality; I certainly didn't say anything above to suggest we are equal to God. Give yourself a downvote.

...if you want to change your errant usage of the phrase "like God" and it's context fine. But you stuffed it and now need ro own that error. Again...WE WERE NEVER MADE LIKE GOD. the bible specifically says "in the image of God". They are two very different things and clearly you had no concept of that difference. I am not the only one who realised your mistake as my criticism was upvoted. The fact you then go and down vote my answer just to get back says a lot about your character.

There's nothing errant about my usage of that phrase - the only error here is what you are illogically reading into it; most likely the same way you errantly read your other thoughts into the scriptures. Your lack of reading comprehension is astounding that you can correctly assert that we are made in the image of God, but then turn around and say that we aren't made to be like God.
