# So before Christ

Tags: life-of-jesus, heaven, cross

Was anyone able to get to heaven before Jesus?

Logically you'd have to say no, because no human being is perfect, except for Christ.

What passages might suggest the opposite?

Comment: i'll give you a short answer

Comment: This is a dupe of "Who saved people before 33ad?"

Answer (score 0):

> Joh 3:13  And no man hath ascended up to heaven, but he that came down from heaven, even the Son of man which is in heaven.
>
> Luk 16:19  There was a certain rich man, which was clothed in purple and fine linen, and fared sumptuously every day:
> Luk 16:20  And there was a certain beggar named Lazarus, which was laid at his gate, full of sores,
> Luk 16:21  And desiring to be fed with the crumbs which fell from the rich man's table: moreover the dogs came and licked his sores.
> Luk 16:22  And it came to pass, that the beggar died, and was carried by the angels into Abraham's bosom: the rich man also died, and was buried;
> Luk 16:23  And in hell he lift up his eyes, being in torments, and seeth Abraham afar off, and Lazarus in his bosom.
> Luk 16:24  And he cried and said, Father Abraham, have mercy on me, and send Lazarus, that he may dip the tip of his finger in water, and cool my tongue; for I am tormented in this flame.
> Luk 16:25  But Abraham said, Son, remember that thou in thy lifetime receivedst thy good things, and likewise Lazarus evil things: but now he is comforted, and thou art tormented.
> Luk 16:26  And beside all this, between us and you there is a great gulf fixed: so that they which would pass from hence to you cannot; neither can they pass to us, that would come from thence.
> Luk 16:27  Then he said, I pray thee therefore, father, that thou wouldest send him to my father's house:
> Luk 16:28  For I have five brethren; that he may testify unto them, lest they also come into this place of torment.
> Luk 16:29  Abraham saith unto him, They have Moses and the prophets; let them hear them.
> Luk 16:30  And he said, Nay, father Abraham: but if one went unto them from the dead, they will repent.
> Luk 16:31  And he said unto him, If they hear not Moses and the prophets, neither will they be persuaded, though one rose from the dead.

Yes, before Christ no one had ascended to heaven, many have after Christ. However there was a place for the Jew Abrahams bosom. We know very little about it there is lots of supposition but the word does not say. We do know not all jews went there some went to hell. It seems that Abraham's bosom was an act of kindness more than an act of salvation. We know very precious little about it contained only in Luke 16 and the like.

Comment: This may come out wrong, but why then did God wait this long before he sent Christ to earth? 

The Messiah was predicted all along.

Comment: @NSAddict post it as another question and ask for a Bible literalist perspective

Comment: It's ok, this question covers this as well:

http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/who-saved-people-before-33ad