# Why was it said Salvation is only through Jesus?

Tags: judaism, global-christianity

It was stated in the answer (https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/15634/45797) to a question ([How were people saved before ~33AD?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/how-were-people-saved-before-33ad)), as follows;

No one, either prior to the cross or since the cross, would ever be saved without that one pivotal event in the history of the world. Christ's death paid the penalty for past sins of Old Testament saints and future sins of New Testament saints.

My questions are

1) whether this view has been held by Jews as well as Christians of all denominations?

2) whether this statement has any scriptural base?

Comment: Seeing as most Jews reject Jesus, of course they wouldn't think everyone is saved by him...

Comment: Funny.  Is it wrong to get clarification on something, which attracts downvoting, here :-)?

Comment: I suspect that the downvotes are because the question doesn't indicate that you have put much research into the matter before asking here.  Typically one should try to find answers first, and then post here only when an answer can't be found.  Please take the time to read about [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576)

Comment: @RayButterworth: Perhaps you are right and I am in wrong place.:-).  Sorry for the inconvenience caused to any one.

Comment: @curiousdanni The Jews were saved by Jesus too, those who like King Solomon professed the Wisdom of God (Wisdom9:16), why? because Jesus is the Wisdom of God.(1Corinthians2:30)

Answer (score 1):

1) By definition, Jesus, as anything other than a human rabbi, belongs to the offshoot of Judaism known as Christianity.  He has nothing to do with traditional Judaism.

2) Acts 4:12 very clearly and explicitly provides a scriptural base for the belief that salvation is only through Jesus:

> Neither is there salvation in any other: for there is none other name under heaven given among men, whereby we must be saved.

Comment: There is no stronger, more concise statement of this in the Bible than Acts 4:12. I would add Luke 24:13-35 (the story of meeting Jesus on the Road to Emmaus) to support the idea that the Old Testament affirms this.

Comment: While statement 1 is accurate,it might be better to say that any Jew who holds that Jesus is the way to salvation is automatically declared a Christian and therefore not a Jew by his fellow Jews.

Comment: The Jews are clearly saved and esp. the elect and their way of salvation can  be found in King Solomon Prayer a Jew. God created all men in His Wisdom and will be save by His Wisdom too. Acts4:12 is not complete without understanding the Apostles teaching on "hidden wisdom".

Answer (score 1):

Several passages from Scripture have already been quoted in answers and comments, but I don't yet see what I regard as the strongest one on this topic, Jesus's own assertion that "I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No man cometh to the Father, but by me" (John 14:6).

Comment: Did the Jews before Christ preach this words knew this condition? Definitely not. But, certainly the Jews are not save thru this particular bible verse but thru the revealed Wisdom of God thru King Solomon. Wisdom9:16 is the salvation of the Jews and all the people before Jesus  came into being.

Comment: In view of your explanation about Jesus being the Wisdom mentioned in the Old Testament, I'd say that the Jews knew that Wisdom is needed to draw near to God. The opposite of Wisdom, foolishness, certainly won't do the job; see Psalm 13:1 (or in Protestant translations, 14:1).

Comment: How can God applied John14:6 to the Jews living before Jesus preach those words? How can the Old Testament Jews claimed faith in Jesus words when they do not even heard of it? Jews are saved by Wisdom is very clear in King Solomon's Prayer.

Comment: @jongricafort Did you  read my comment? You seem to be agreeing with it.

Comment: Yes, what Im asking is John14:6, because the O.P particularly asked the salvation of the Jews before Jesus time.Are you saying that the OT Jews was subject to John14:6 too?

Comment: @jongricafort Yes, the O.T. Jews are included in John 14:6, and your answer explains one way that could be: They could come to the Father by divine Wisdom, which is Jesus. Of course, their arrival in heaven would have to wait until after the sacrifice of Calvary reopened heaven to humans, and at that time their arrival would involve Jesus not only as divine Wisdom but also as the incarnate Redeemer.

Comment: I agree.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Why was it said Salvation is only through Jesus?*

Because the scriptures clearly teaches it in the famous verse in John Gospel;

> John 3:16 New International Version (NIV)
>
> 16 *For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.*

But the Jews living before the time of Jesus Christ believe they can be save by God not thru Jesus Christ but as King Solomon professed the Jews can be saved by Wisdom.

> **Solomon’s Prayer for Wisdom**
>
> “O God of my ancestors and Lord of mercy,
>
> who have made all things by your word,
>
> and by your wisdom have formed humankind...
>
> Who has learned your counsel,
>
> unless you have given wisdom
>
> and sent your holy spirit from on high?
>
> And thus the paths of those on earth were set right,
>
> and people were taught what pleases you,
>
> **and were saved by wisdom.**”

King Solomon profess that the ***Jews are saved by Wisdom.***

We can also relate salvation of other religions not only Jews in the recent words of Pope Francis;

> Freedom is a right of every person: each individual enjoys the freedom of belief, thought, expression and action. ***The pluralism and the diversity of religions, colour, sex, race and language are willed by God in His wisdom***, through which He created human beings. This divine wisdom is the source from which the right to freedom of belief and the freedom to be different derives. Therefore, the fact that people are forced to adhere to a certain religion or culture must be rejected, as too the imposition of a cultural way of life that others do not accept;
>
> - Justice based on mercy is the path to follow in order to achieve a dignified life to which every human being has a right;
>     http://w2.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/travels/2019/outside/documents/papa-francesco_20190204_documento-fratellanza-umana.html

This words ***"The pluralism and the diversity of religions, colour, sex, race and language are willed by God in His wisdom"***, is the answer to your particular question on those people living before Jesus Christ.

While the bible teaches that there are no other names given in Heaven on which man can be save, but the Old Testament clearly teaches that people can be save by Wisdom.

Is there a contradiction between the gospel and old testament scriptures? None, why?

St.Paul teaches Jesus is the Wisdom of God. So the people in the old testament embracing the Wisdom of God like King Solomon professed is actually Jesus Christ personified.

> **Spiritual Wisdom**
>   6 *However, we speak wisdom among those who are mature, yet not the wisdom of this age, nor of the rulers of this age, who are coming to nothing. 7 But we speak the wisdom of God in a mystery, the hidden wisdom which God [j]ordained before the ages for our glory, 8 which none of the rulers of this age knew; for had they known, they would not have crucified the Lord of glory.*(1 Corinthian2:6)
>
> ***But of Him you are in Christ Jesus, who became for us wisdom from God***—*and righteousness and sanctification and redemption—* (1Corinthian2:30)

So the bible is clear all mankind in the Old and New Testament are saved by the Wisdom of God. Jesus became the wisdom of God, but before Jesus the Wisdom of God that saved people in the old testament already exist.

Pope Francis was biblically correct pluralism and diversity of religions are ***"Willed by God in His Wisdom" because He can save all mankind thru His Wisdom.***