Will judgment by scales be used on the last day?
A hand was writing on the wall and it was judging a ruler, it said that he has been weighed on the scales and found wanting. God weighed the good deeds against the bad deeds of a ruler here before passing judgment to him. Will this technique be used on judgment day or will it apply to people who lived during the era of the old covenant?
Daniel 5:27

you have been weighed on the scales [of righteousness] and found deficient

This is because even Paul said people must appear before a seat of judgment:

For we must all appear before the judgment seat of Christ, that each one may receive what is due to him for the things done while in the body, whether good or bad.(2 Corinthians 5:10)

Will all bad deeds be accounted for together with the good deeds, put on a balance which decides your fate?
This is because there were millions of people who lived in the Old Testament era and the name of Jesus had not yet been given. Since all must appear before a seat of judgment and its not their fault to be be born in that era, then a scale that measures their righteousness against their wickedness must be used?

Daniel 5:27: The Authorised Version says, “Thou art weighed in the balances” and the NIV says, “You have been weighed on the scales and found wanting.”  Which Bible translation says Belshazzar had been “weighed on the scales [of righteousness]”?  And if “of righteousness” is valid, whose righteousness?

@Lesley, the point is that a means of judgment is delivered using a scale.  Something was weighed on a scale for God is no liar.

“You have been weighed on the scales and found wanting.” (Daniel 5:27)
The events described in Daniel chapter 5 were real. The people were real. The vision of the hand writing the words on the wall of the palace produced real words.  But where were the scales?  When was Belshazzar weighed?
Daniel 5:27 means that Belshazzar had been measured in the light of God’s standards and found wanting.  God already knew of his sins, not least of which was worshiping false gods and defiling the temple utensils. The biblical account of those events nowhere says that Belshazzar was placed on literal, physical weighing scales in the banquet room. The judgment had already taken place, and Belshazzar died that very night.
Here are some examples of how figurative language is used in the Bible:
Exodus 13:9 and 16 which speak of God’s laws being written on doorframes, gates, and foreheads, suggest God was using figurative language to emphasize the importance of obeying His laws.
The use of anthropomorphism, a form of figurative language, sometimes describes God in physical terms, as if He has a body. God does not have a body – He is Spirit.
Being a poetic book, Psalms employs figurative language extensively. The “rock” in Psalm 18:2 is metaphorical.
Job 6:2-3: If only my anguish could be weighed and all my misery be placed on the scales! It would surely outweigh the sand of the seas… How can anguish be weighed?
Job 31:6: Let God weigh me in honest scales and he will know that I am blameless. How can blamelessness be weighed?
Psalm 62:9: Lowborn men are but a breath, the highborn are but a lie; if weighed on a balance, they are nothing; together they are only a breath. How can you weigh a lie or a breath?
The Revelation of Jesus Christ as given to the Apostle Paul is filled with symbolic figures. The beasts with numerous heads and horns are not physical, literal beasts.  The harlot is not a literal harlot but is a symbol of false religion. The language used is figurative.
You ask if judgment by scales will be used on the last day or if it will apply to people who lived during the era of the old covenant.
The image of the scales of justice is a powerful metaphor.  Every person who has ever lived will be subject to God’s righteous judgment at the last day.  Every person will account for how they lived, whether they trusted in God and in His promises or not. Will literal weighing scales be used to weigh every person who has died?
No. The scales are a metaphor for how a holy and righteous God views our deeds, our motives and whether or not we repented for our sins and turned to Him in faith.
Finally, you ask if all bad deeds be accounted for together with the good deeds and put on a balance which decides your fate.
You cannot weigh deeds on scales.  Anyway, no amount of “good deeds” can ever outweigh “bad deeds”.  Eternal life is a free and unmerited gift from God who reads our hearts and minds and who knows who belong to Him.  Our fate is sealed at the point of our death:

Just as man is destined to die once, and after that to face judgment, so Christ was sacrificed once to take away the sins of many people; and he will appear a second time, not to bear sin, but to bring salvation to those who are waiting for him. (Hebrews 9:27-28)


What about people who didn't know Jesus, people who lived during the old testament ? How will they be judged when the name of Jesus had not been given yet? There has to be some balance to measure their righteousness against their wickedness

That is an entirely separate question and has been answered elsewhere on CSE. See the link posted below. Job knew God and had faith that he would see him at the last day (Job 19:25-27). Abraham, Moses and many other O.T. people had faith in God, and believed in His promises. Read Hebrews chapter 8 which proves that before the Son of God came to earth, men and women who had faith in God and in His promises were assured of the resurrection. Read this: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/how-were-people-saved-prior-to-33-ad

You have only mentioned Jews, what about the gentiles of the old testament who lived righteous lives?

You are now going off-topic and I will not engage further with you. Please ask a new question about this and I will be happy to provide a full, biblical answer.

To imagine an amount of good deeds that can outweigh bad deeds on a scale of justice is not in keeping with the full biblical revelation.  The disposition of sin within a person renders every deed as evil before God until such time as that person is regenerated through repentance and belief and a life of faith begins.
A more illustrative way to consider it may be like this:  If, in making an omelette, a rotten egg (bad deed) is cracked into the bowl, how many fresh eggs (good deeds) must be cracked in to overcome the rotten egg?  Obviously, there is no amount of good eggs that can accomplish this and the whole mess must be scrapped for a brand new start.  Ye must be born again.
Nebuchadnezzar had gone through quite a process until, by God's grace and mercy, he went from saying "and who is that God that shall deliver you out of my hands?" (Daniel 3:15) to declaring "Now I Nebuchadnezzar praise and extol and honour the King of heaven, all whose works are truth, and his ways judgment: and those that walk in pride he is able to abase." (Daniel 4:37).
Thus was Nebuchadnezzar justified, not by his deeds, but by his humble confession of faith in the truth and judgement of the King of Heaven:  By his repentance and reliance upon the degree of Divine revelation he had been given.
Those of us who have the full revelation understand that it is the sacrifice of Christ, the Son of the Living God (who was known in God's economy but yet to come for Nebuchadnezzar) that ultimately renders each person guilty or innocent.  We also understand by that same full revelation that everyone, everywhere is without excuse.
Belshazzar was Nebuchadnezzar's son (5:1) and was well aware of his father's pride, humiliation, restoration, and confession of faith.  Certainly it was more than a little dramatic for his father to go from king of the known world to living as a beast of the field for 7 years before being restored to sanity and the throne.
Belshazzar learned nothing.

Then they brought the golden vessels that were taken out of the temple of the house of God which was at Jerusalem; and the king, and his princes, his wives, and his concubines, drank in them. They drank wine, and praised the gods of gold, and of silver, of brass, of iron, of wood, and of stone. - Daniel 5:3-4

There is nothing wrong with eating and drinking.  There is everything wrong with disdaining the glory of the one true God and praising false gods.  There is no good deed that he could have done while his heart was lifted up in pride against Almighty God. Thus it is that Belshazzar's heart was weighed, measured, and found wanting not his deeds:

And thou his son, O Belshazzar, hast not humbled thine heart, though thou knewest all this; But hast lifted up thyself against the Lord of heaven - Daniel 5:22-23a

Thou art weighed in the balances and found wanting.  The Bible does not say that his deeds were weighed.  To plead acceptance before God on the basis of one's deeds is to put Him in the position of debtor, as if to say "I have done such and such and you, oh God, now owe me something".  Let in never be so!


For we must all appear before the judgment seat of Christ, that each one may receive what is due to him for the things done while in the body, whether good or bad.(2 Corinthians 5:10)

The "we" in this passage is not referring to all people.  Paul is writing this letter to the Church at Corinth (please see 2 Corinthians 1:1); i.e., to believers.  Those before the judgement seat (Bema) of Christ are Christians and they are 1) already credited as righteous by faith, 2) being assigned rewards based upon their deeds of faith; they are not being assigned salvation.
Unbelievers will appear before the Great White Throne and their judgement will be based upon their lack of entry in the Lamb's Book of Life:

And I saw the dead, small and great, stand before God; and the books were opened: and another book was opened, which is the book of life: and the dead were judged out of those things which were written in the books, according to their works...And whosoever was not found written in the book of life was cast into the lake of fire. - Revelation 20:12&15

Some believe that the Bema seat of Christ and the Great White Throne are one and the same.  Others perceive two distinct and separate judgements.  For the purposes of this question it simply does not matter.  Either way it is the names written in the Book of Life that indicate salvation or destruction and not deeds weighed on a scale.  To rely upon deeds rather than upon Christ is a wide path that leads to destruction.


All humanity is to account for themselves before God, who will judge them by Jesus Christ. Both in O.T. times, N.T. times, and right until the Day of Resurrection and Judgment, the Bible shows that it is faith that God looks for. Not wishful thinking, or just hoping that one will have outweighed their bad deeds with good deeds, but faith in God. Knowing the favour and love of God, experiencing how gracious he is to them, their response is to love and obey God, which is evidence of faith.
That is why God was pleased with Noah, and with Abraham, before the Mosaic law was given. That is why the Bible commends their faith in God before any circumcision was required. Hebrews chapter 11 shows that. Too much to copy here. The point is, it wasn't performing any rituals, or being strictly legalistic keeping laws that enabled faithful people to experience the grace of God while on Earth. It was their reverential awe of God and trembling at his word so as to do it, that God noticed. Those faithful believers knew that every judgment of God was utterly righteous, and they trembled at the very thought of displeasing God by wanton disobedience. They knew they failed his perfect standards, but that he was merciful, loving, and gracious to forgive their sins when they confessed them to him. Then they experienced the grace of God.
There are far too many scriptures in the Bible to detail here. From Genesis to Revelation, this is a consistent theme. Another consistent theme is that God never overlooks sin, as if it had not been committed, or symbolically "sweeps it under the carpet". All sin has to be punished. And "the wages of sin is death" Romans 6:23 yet that sentence adds, "but the gift of God is everlasting life through Jesus Christ our Lord."
Faith in God's only means of being pardoned has always been required of those who seek God, to have their sins freely forgiven. People in the O.T. had to have the same faith in God's righteousness as everybody else thereafter. The O.T. nowhere teaches that doing more good deeds than bad deeds would "swing" the balance in their favour. God finds wanting those who keep doing bad (= sin) and, if they will not repent and seek his forgiveness, they won't get it. Belshazzar discovered that the very night the writing on the wall appeared. Here is one of many Bible texts that warn every person:

"I am not ashamed of the gospel of Christ: for it is the power of God
unto  salvation to every one that believeth; to the Jew first,
and also to the Greek. For therein is the righteousness of God
revealed from faith to faith: as it is written, The just shall live by faith. For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven
against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of men, who hold the truth
in unrighteousness...
...the goodness of God leadeth to repentance. But after thy
hardness and impenitent heart treasurest up unto thyself wrath against
the day of wrath and revelation of the righteous judgment of God; who
will render to every man according to his deeds: to him who by patient
continuance in well doing seek for glory and honour and immortality,
eternal life. But unto them that are contentious, and do not obey the
truth, but obey unrighteousness, indignation and wrath... In the day
when God shall judge the secrets of men by Jesus Christ according to
my gospel."   Romans 1:16-18 & 2:4-16 A.V. [Emphasis mine]

I stop there so that the crucial points are not skimmed over. Belief - Faith - Repentance - Secrets.
When it comes to our being judged, Christ knows all our secrets. Everybody else might think what fine people we are, known for charitable deeds, loving our families, being generous, paying all our taxes, being law-abiding citizens, worshipping God regularly (and whatever else you might think of as 'good deeds'). But what if all that is done as if our 'payment' for some kind of imagined 'spiritual insurance policy'? What if our charitableness and generosity is viewed by us as 'payment' (so that God must give us a dividend?)? What if our apparent love for our families hides resentment and hatred in our hearts against some? What if our public worship is done to ensure others will see that and be impressed with our religiosity? These are secret things - not deeds - but Jesus knows our motives and what we really think. He warned that even to think lustfully about a woman was effectively to commit adultery. How many unspoken, sinful desires have we had, but because we have not (so far) enacted them, we think that won't 'count' on the Day of Judgment? Read more in Romans:

"How then shall God judge the world? ...both Jews and Gentiles are all
under sin. As it is written, 'There is none righteous, no, not one...
there is none that doeth good, no, not one...' [quoting Micah 7:9,
Psalm 14:1-3 & 53:1-3]...But now the righteousness of God without the
law is manifested, being witnessed by the law and the prophets, even
the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ unto all
and upon all them that believe: for there is no difference: For all
have sinned, and come short of the glory of God; being justified
freely by his grace through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus,
whom God hath set forth, propitiation through faith in his blood, to
declare his righteousness for the remission of sins that are past,
through the forbearance of God; to declare at this time his
righteousness; that he might be just, and the justifier of him which
believeth in Jesus.
Where is the boasting then? It is excluded. By what law? of works?
Nay, but by the law of faith. Therefore we conclude that a man is
justified by faith without the deeds of the law." Ibid. 3:6-28 [Emphasis mine]

Until we agree with God's basis of judgment, and put faith in the only means of securing his free, unmerited pardon for our repented-of sins, no amount of supposed 'good deeds' will count towards eternal salvation. No mention of scales in those Bible texts; for who can weigh Belief - Faith - Repentance - Secrets? So, the answer to the question is a simple, "No."

Was Belshazzar so special that he was placed on a scale for his judgment while others were not?

In the NT, faith in the only begotten son of God is what is required to inherit eternal life, you have to believe in him for even in the days of Noah God required that world to believe in Noah and they did not believe and the floods took them all away, it will be the same in this age. Some men will believe in Jesus and will get onboard the ark of Jesus before the floods or the wrath of God is unleashed on the ungodly.

Insightful and perceptive. Challenging and penetrating. Up-voted +1.

I think you’re conflating different things here. Belshazzar’s judgement in Daniel was a in-this-life death sentence, a “ok you’re done with receiving more time to repent” declaration that was then carried out that night. It was described in figurative language as Belshazzar the man having been weighed in the scales and having been found lacking. He wasn’t the man he should have been given the example of his father who repented before the Lord, while Belshazzar hardened his heart and plunged headlong into sin. Eternal judgment is different and the Bible makes it clear that…

…unless we have faith in Jesus, we have no good works to be counted  (credited actually; we can never earn anything good) in our favor, only bad.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany  We are all judged without partiality by God, though some individuals experience his adverse judgment before they die, or (in Belshazzar's case) dying that very night. Yet everyone then has to face the judgment throne of Christ at the last day. That is when everything hidden will be revealed and our eternal destiny declared. Your own Q asked about judgment at the last day, which is what I addressed. Belshazzar still has that awful day to face; like all of us, but for those found "in Christ", it will not be awful. Awesome, yes, but not awful due to the grace of God in Christ

LDS perspective:
According to King Benjamin, you have no merits to speak of. You'll never bring God into debt. The following quotes are from the Book of Mormon, if that wasn't clear.
Mosiah 2:21-25

21 I say unto you that if ye should serve him who has created you from
the beginning, and is preserving you from day to day, by lending you
breath, that ye may live and move and do according to your own will,
and even supporting you from one moment to another—I say, if ye should
serve him with all your whole souls yet ye would be unprofitable
servants.
22 And behold, all that he requires of you is to keep his
commandments; and he has promised you that if ye would keep his
commandments ye should prosper in the land; and he never doth vary
from that which he hath said; therefore, if ye do keep his
commandments he doth bless you and prosper you.
23 And now, in the first place, he hath created you, and granted unto
you your lives, for which ye are indebted unto him.
24 And secondly, he doth require that ye should do as he hath
commanded you; for which if ye do, he doth immediately bless you; and
therefore he hath paid you. And ye are still indebted unto him, and
are, and will be, forever and ever; therefore, of what have ye to
boast?
25 And now I ask, can ye say aught of yourselves? I answer you, Nay.
Ye cannot say that ye are even as much as the dust of the earth; yet
ye were created of the dust of the earth; but behold, it belongeth to
him who created you.

We are always, ALWAYS, saved by grace and mercy, not by justice.
Mosiah 3:18-19

18 For behold he judgeth, and his judgment is just; and the infant
perisheth not that dieth in his infancy; but men drink damnation to
their own souls except they humble themselves and become as little
children, and believe that salvation was, and is, and is to come, in
and through the atoning blood of Christ, the Lord Omnipotent.
19 For the natural man is an enemy to God, and has been from the fall
of Adam, and will be, forever and ever, unless he yields to the
enticings of the Holy Spirit, and putteth off the natural man and
becometh a saint through the atonement of Christ the Lord, and
becometh as a child, submissive, meek, humble, patient, full of love,
willing to submit to all things which the Lord seeth fit to inflict
upon him, even as a child doth submit to his father.

So maybe, kind of, one could say judgement can be seen as using scales, but they are never tipped in your favor. Only Christ can save us.

What about King Nebuchadnezzar? why did Go find it in his favor to weigh him on the scales before passing judgment onto him? God has to judge first before rewarding or punishing. Why did he need a balance and what was being weighed on that balance?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany What is it you are after? You want to understand whether the flowery language the scriptures sometimes have refers to something literal of is a metaphor?

There is no literal language here, this is an actual event of a man being judged by God. God explains why the kingdom is being passed from the Babylonians to the Medo-Persians. He says it is a consequence of his judgment on Nebuchadnezzar, in this judgment he says that Nebuchadnezzar has been weighed on the scales of righteousness (these scales are in heaven) and found wanting.

It is not Nebuchadnezzar who had been found wanting but King Belshazzar.

Upvoted, and I greatly appreciate that you said which perspective you presented. It makes the site more "clean" and "easier to read", ultimately more helpful and useful. This is how answers should look!

@kutschkem Who is King Benjamin, and where is the land of Zarahemia? The events recorded in the Book of Mosiah are from about 130 B.C. yet in chapters 2 and 3 it mimics the book of Job, the Gospels of Matthew and Luke and Paul’s letter to the Romans and the Corinthians. Or are we to believe that it was Job, Jesus and Paul who were quoting from the Book of Mosiah? What came first – the Bible or the Book of Mormon?

@Lesley <3 This is not the place for this discussion. The right place would be a question. But I added a sentence making it clear that I am quoting from the Book of Mormon, to make sure it's clear what I am doing in the answer.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Please indicate what Bible translation refers to the "scales of righteousness" that you keep mentioning.

@MikeBorden, Its a Bible app on my phone that I use for quick references, I will check and update the post with the translation used in that app, but I will capture a screenshot and attach to the post.

My understanding of the last judgement from an Orthodox perspective.
Ultimately the final judgement is based on love.

While the terms of scales is not often used, the final judgement is thought of very specifically on "Meatfare" Sunday, or more correctly "Sunday of the Last Judgement" where this Ikon is displayed.

This is a greats visual representation of (some of the) orthodox understanding of the last judgement. It is mostly inspired not from the book of Daniel, but rather from (Matthew 25:31-46) where Christ explains the sheep and the goats. However, there are "scales" in the Ikon.
The icon of the Sunday of the Last Judgment incorporates all of the elements of the parable from Matthew 25:31-46.
In this passage Christ explains how acts of love to other people, are like acts of love to Himself directly. The kingdom of God is given to his sheep who were compassionate and served others. They are told: "Come, you blessed of My Father, and inherit the kingdom."
Similarly the goats, who were not compassionate, who did not serve others: Are told "Depart from Me, you cursed, into the everlasting fire prepared for the devil and his angels”
These two passages are on the scrolls held by the angels in the Ikon. The left for the sheep and the right for the goats. (Note that the Sheep are on the Right hand side of Christ)
Between the two angels in the Ikon is the "Book of life" from revelations.
Underneath the Book, the Angel in the Green. Is the archangel Michael holding the scales of judgement. It is not very apparent in this Ikon, so here is another Ikon of the final judgement.

Before the throne, the progenitors of the human race, Adam and Eve, bow before Christ. In the center of the icon is the Archangel Michael. He is holding the scales of judgment and is surrounded by the books that contain the works of each person (Revelation 20:11-13)

As this particular Sunday focuses on the upcoming Lent season... there is another theme within: Love.
When Christ comes to judge us, what will be the criterion of His judgment?

The parable of the Last Judgment answers: love—not a mere humanitarian
concern for abstract justice and the anonymous “poor,” but concrete
and personal love for the human person—the specific persons that we
encounter each day in our lives.
Christian love is the “possible impossibility” to see Christ in another person, whoever he or she is, and whom God, in His eternal
and mysterious plan, has decided to introduce into my life, be it only
for a few moments, not as an occasion for a “good deed” or an exercise
in philanthropy, but as the beginning of an eternal companionship in
God Himself.
The parable of the Last Judgment is about Christian love. Not all of
us are called to work for “humanity,” yet each one of us has received
the gift and the grace of Christ’s love. We know that all persons
ultimately need this personal love—the recognition in them of their
unique soul in which the beauty of the whole creation is reflected in
a unique way. We also know that people are in prison and are sick and
thirsty and hungry because that personal love has been denied them.
And, finally, we know that however narrow and limited the framework of
our personal existence, each one of us has been made responsible for a
tiny part of the Kingdom of God, made responsible by that very gift of
Christ’s love. Thus, on whether or not we have accepted this
responsibility, on whether we have loved or refused to love, shall we
be judged.
-GoArch

