# Herod great and Jesus birth death dates

Tags: christology, herod

If Herod the great died 4 bc

And Jesus was born 2 bc

How is explained that Herod great was alive at the time of Jesus birth

Perhaps I have my dates wrong yet they are what I found on internet

Regards Richard

Comment: see https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/2531/22319

Comment: Welcome! This question has already been asked, so I've closed this one as a duplicate. I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).